# Check the source of a toast message

Tags: toast-notifications

Notifications have a handy feature where lo g pressing brings up the **App Info** option, which let's you track down the source of strange notifications.

I keep getting toast messages and I can't figure out where they're coming from. Is there any way to track down what app is sending them?

Comment: Is your device rooted?

Comment: Yes my device is rooted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible on rooted devices with Android 4.0.3 or later.  It requires installation of [Xposed framework](http://repo.xposed.info/) and a module called "Buttered Toast".  This module appends the name of the app to the text of the toast message.

1. Download and side-load the latest version of Xposed module installer from [here](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer).
2. Open the Xposed Installer app, tap on "Framework", and tap on "Install/Update" button.  This copies all the necessary libraries and scripts to the /system partition.
3. Reboot your device.
4. Once the device boots back up, open the Xposed Installer app, tap on "Download", tap the search button (looks like a magnifying glass) on top-right, and type in "buttered toast" (without quotes).
5. The module should be listed under the "Not Installed" section. Tap on the "Buttered Toast" module, tap on the "Versions" tab, tap the Download button.  This downloads the module.
6. Once the module downloads, it will attempt to install itself.  Tap the "Install" button on the presented dialog, and then tap the "Done" button to get back to Xposed Installer app.
7. Go back to Xposed Installer's main screen, and tap on "Modules".  Tap the empty check-mark next to the "ButteretToast" module to activate it.
8. Close the Xposed Installer app and reboot your device.

Once the device boots up again, all the toasts will have their corresponding app's name added in the beginning.  You may also want to install a similar "Burnt Toast" module (repeat steps 4 through 8 for this module,) which also adds the app's icon into every toast.

Comment: Awesome! thanks.  one question, can Buttered and Burnt work together, or is it one or the other?

Comment: They do work together, but the toasts to get kind of cramped and over-sized :)

Comment: Thanks! I knew about Xposed but never really knew what it did.  I've used it for a Netflix problem on an earlier ROM.