# What app is causing this toast?

Tags: toast-notifications

Does anyone know what app is causing this "check network connection" toast?

[image: mystery toast]

Notes app shown below is unrelated as far as I know, the toast shows when I turn off my data regardless of what app is currently foregrounded.

Comment: Open Android studio or eclipse and connect your phone and check the logcat ... You might find something in there

Comment: you can check this link : http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/84582/check-the-source-of-a-toast-message

Comment: Any cloud software installed that might just try to sync?

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://android.stackexchange.com/q/159529/96277

Answer (score 2):

This toast is generated by the Pinterest app whenever it tries to sync without a network connection. As far as I know, the only way to remove it is by uninstalling it. You could also try force-closing the app, but this toast is so uninformative and intrusive that I uninstalled Pinterest on principle.

Comment: Yeah, I can confirm, it belongs to the Pinterest app.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to use Tasker with AutoNotification plugin. I had it display a Toast with app name whether it intercepted any Toast not from Tasker itself.

Just did that to find a badly designed app asking to "Please activate mobile data": Webhop.

(The question might be a bit old, but the (general type of) problem seems to have remained unsolved judging by the answers here and in Google search. So there you go.)