# Getting toast message with text sending

Tags: malware, asus-zenfone-2

I'm using Asus 551 with lollipop. I have numerous apps installed. Recently, I started getting toast notification with the text **Sending...**.

This usually occurs when I'm using Facebook, whatsapp and such apps. It seems fishy.

I recently uninstalled es file explorer after a similar issue was reported by users. It was showing similar toast with some Chinese text.

Is there a way I could find out what app is causing this?

Here is a screen shot:

[image: Screenshot]

I tried the `dumpsys` command, as suggested by @Firelord. Then used some of the apps, got the **Sending...** toast a couple of times, then again ran the `dumpsys` command, but there was no difference in the log. Here is how it looked before and after:

[image: Dumpsys log]

Comment: Any app actively showing a toast would be shown under the output of the command `dumpsys window windows`? Furthermore, if it is Android 5 or above, you can use `dumpsys appops` command to filter things out.

Comment: @Firelord I couldn't spot a difference in the outputs after using `dumpsys appops`, please see the update question.

Comment: Also, I am going to try this Notifications, Toasts logging app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.coconuts.pastnotifications&hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that it was the **Sim ToolKit** that was showing the toast notification. I have recently switched to a Reliance Jio Sim (India), which has free unlimited calls and 4G data until December! Now that is too good to believe and fishy.

I used this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.coconuts.pastnotifications&hl=en
And allowed it to monitor the Toasts via Accessibility settings.

For now I have **Force Stopped** the process. The toasts are gone, should they come back, I will disable the Jio Sim itself.